# copy records from db2 to h2 using spring batch

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-batch

I am trying to copy 100k records from `db2` to `h2` using `spring batch` but I am facing the following issue.

```
    @Bean
    public RepositoryItemReader<TIPACLDEntity> itemReader(){
        RepositoryItemReader<TIPACLDEntity> repositoryItemReader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
        repositoryItemReader.setRepository(tipacldRepository);
        repositoryItemReader.setMethodName("findAll");
        repositoryItemReader.setPageSize(2000);
        Map<String, Sort.Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
        repositoryItemReader.setSort(sorts);
        return repositoryItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("gcms-extract-step")
                .<TIPACLDEntity, IpmClringMsgEntity>chunk(100)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .processor(itemProcessor)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();

        return step;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(10);
        return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        Job job = jobBuilderFactory.get("gcms-extract-job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step())
                .build();
        return job;
    }
```

I think it is not able to create pages of size 2000 properly and jump to the next page. Is there anything I am missing in the batch config?`

The error is:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

The query created for the second page is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT inner2_.*,
          rownumber() over(ORDER BY ORDER OF inner2_) AS rownumber_
   FROM
     (SELECT tipacldent0_.CLR_LVL_DTL_ID AS clr_lvl_1_0_,
             tipacldent0_.PRCSS_DT AS prcss_dt2_0_,
             tipacldent0_.CLR_DTL_REC_TXT AS clr_dtl_3_0_,
             tipacldent0_.CNSMD_SW AS cnsmd_sw4_0_,
             tipacldent0_.CRTE_TS AS crte_ts5_0_,
             tipacldent0_.PARTN_NUM AS partn_nu6_0_,
             tipacldent0_.PRCSS_AGRMT_ID AS prcss_ag7_0_,
             tipacldent0_.UPDT_TS AS updt_ts8_0_
      FROM TIPACLD tipacldent0_
      FETCH FIRST 4000 ROWS ONLY) AS inner2_
) AS inner1_
WHERE rownumber_ > 2000
ORDER BY rownumber_
```

Comment: please check once if you are able to run the generated query directly to the database and it is giving response.